Rescue/Emergency mode with Fedora 12 and GNU GRUB 0.97
I have a problem with a VM with fedora 12. When I try to start up the VM, it gets blocked with this message.

Looking in differents forums, they mention to get in rescue/emergency mode where I can use commands to check the disk state and other stuff.
I saw that I need to get into GRUB screen in order to activate the emergency mode, but I couldn't find the way to activate the emergency/rescue mode in GRUB 0.97 with Fedora 12. I checked the manuals and it doesn't mention how to do it. So, my question is: There is a way to activate an emergency/rescude mode in these environment?
My GRUB looks like this:



Welcome to the site. Please don't post screenshots of console output. They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Download an install/netboot ISO, boot from it, do what you need.

You should be able to e edit the kernel parameter line and add a parameter for recovery. Not sure which Fedora uses, could try single or init=/bin/bash or the like, and perhaps remove quiet if it's there. If it's about audit specifically you can also try audit=0

The avc: denied { create } ... error message suggests SELinux labelling issues. If you had been running with SELinux disabled, but the the disabling had not been persistent (i.e. the SELINUX state variable in /etc/sysconfig/selinux was not set to "disabled"), then SELinux may be getting enabled on boot and may be causing problems with files that were not properly labeled while SELinux was disabled. After gaining root access with frostschutz's advice, run mount -o remount,rw /, then touch /.autorelabel (or edit /etc/sysconfig/selinux to your preference) and reboot.

Thanks for the comments, @frostschutz I archieved after instead of doing e I used a to append into the grub line of the image and using single. After that, @telcoM I disabled SELinux and that problem didn't happen again. But now I have another problem. I checked /var/log/messages and I saw these two lines: <See the next comment to see the log messages**>. I understand that's the issue that does not let start my GUI. I checked that maybe is something about permissions ¿maybe?, but worked until now

**kdm: :0[1165]: Received unknown or unexpected command -2 from greeter,
kdm: :0[1165] Abnormal termination of greeter for display: 0, code: 127, signal 0

Thanks to @frostschutz answer I did it. Instead of using e I used a so I could append into the line and at the end of the line I added single. With this, I could enter the emergency mode and do whatever I needed to do with root acces.
I repost it as an answer so it is more visible.
